# Sending data from c#.net app to another desktop app

Tags: c#

I am making a c# winform app . I am trying to read a mobile number from a file and a message stored in a string . I want to pass this mobile number and message from my winform app to another windows desktop app, as shown in this picture:

[image]

but i can't able to pass the data from my app to this desktop app. What will the code for that?

Comment: I take it that the other desktop app is not one that you wrote yourself? Does it have an API?

Comment: Yeah the other desktop app is not written by me. I wrote the app sending sms and i want to pass data from it to mobo robo write message app. Moreover it doesn't have an api

Comment: Then unless that other app has an API to use then it's not going to be easy to pass it any details. I suppose you could automate copy/paste into that app, but nobody is going to write the code for you.

Comment: Alright . Trying to get its api now.

Comment: You want to inject data, not to send it. It can be done but not in all cases and depends on other app. There is no guarantee that such API exists - probably it does not exist in the case from picture.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C >> Not the exact code which you want.. but might help you

Comment: So what will be the best solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use windows hooks. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: its not the best way to handle this kind of problem